# Find all firewalled connections from a binary from the client

Tags: firewall

I have a binary file that is failing with no helpful information.  It works in the prod domain, but it is failing in the dev domain.  I believe it is failing due to firewall rules.  I'd like to figure out what cross-domain firewall exceptions to request.

Is there a way to capture what failed connections it is attempting when I run the binary?  That is, from the client rather than the looking at the firewall logs.

(RedHat 7 environment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to trace network system calls produced by your program:

```
strace -f -e trace=network ./yourprogram
```

You should be able to see `connect` system calls produced by your program. Take note of IP address (`sin_addr`) and the port (`sin_port`) on these lines.

Further, you can run tcpdump to look inside traffic to those IP:port:

```
tcpdump -i any host FILTERED_IP and port FILTERED_PORT
```

Comment: Thanks.  This let me rule out firewall issues.